# i can't pass my bootstrap5 card to be in horizontal line

Tags: bootstrap-5

this is the code i have write this morning, i want pass the audio cards to be in horizontal line in bootstrap 5 but i can't please help me do that.

when i add col-4 inside col nothing is change please how can i do this ?

```
 {% for audio in songs %}
      <div class="container">
           <div class="row">
                <div class="col-4">
                     <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                          <img src="{{audio.image.url}}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                          <div class="card-body">
                               <h3 class="card-title">{{audio.book_title}}</h3>
                               <h5 class="card-title">{{audio.author}}</h5>
                               <p class="card-text">{{audio.artist}}</p>
                          </div>
                     </div> 
                <audio controls controlsList="nodownload" style="margin-right: -100px;"> 
                   <source src="{{audio.file.url}}">
                </audio>
           </div>
          </div>
      </div>
 {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Run the `for` loop inside the `row` class. Your audio cards will be in horizontal. The code becomes:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
        {% for audio in songs %}
            <div class="col-4">
                 <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                      <img src="{{audio.image.url}}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                      <div class="card-body">
                           <h3 class="card-title">{{audio.book_title}}</h3>
                           <h5 class="card-title">{{audio.author}}</h5>
                           <p class="card-text">{{audio.artist}}</p>
                      </div>
                 </div> 
                <audio controls controlsList="nodownload" style="margin-right: -100px;"> 
                   <source src="{{audio.file.url}}">
                </audio>
           </div>
       {% endfor %}
   </div>
</div>
```

`row` is used for the entire row of the viewport, and col for one element inside it. So your previous code was basically making a row for every card, hence all cards were going in a new line. You need to make 1 row, and then put all `col` (cards) inside it.

Comment: thank you so much its now working fine but, I don't know why my custom audio player player does not forward the song for a second ? please how can I solve that

Comment: If the solution helped you, please accept it as an answer. And make a new question for the audio issue with some code, someone will help you!

Comment: hello do you have a working fiddle, with audio player, I really like your answer, not sure why adm did not mark it as answer, I up voted you